# Problema SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: nodejs, reactjs

Hola comunidad subi mi proyecto a heroku y al correrlo la parte del servidor no me muestra la consulta con la informacion e imagenes.

https://astronomicfrontend.herokuapp.com/

Código del server

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const fs = require('fs');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 9000;
const API_KEY = "";

function getAstronomicPicturesInfo() {
    const data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("resources/astronomicImages.json"))
    return data.map(function(obj){
        return {
        "explanation" : obj.explanation,
        "hdurl" : obj.hdurl,
        "title" : obj.title,
        "url" : obj.url
    }});    
}

//routes
app.get("/api", async (req,res) =>{
    const filter = req.query.filter
    const pageSize = req.query.pageSize
    const page = req.query.page  
    const allData = getAstronomicPicturesInfo()
    let resultData;
    if(filter) {
        resultData = allData.filter(item => item.title.includes(filter))
    } else {
        resultData = allData
    }    
    if(pageSize && page) {
        resultData = resultData.slice((page - 1) * pageSize, page * pageSize)
    }
    res.send(resultData)  
});


app.listen(PORT, console.log(`server started on port" ${PORT}`)
```

Comment: Pareciera que lo que devuelve readFileSync contiene un dato no válido que no puede parsear. Intenta separar ese método aparte y valida lo que te está devolviendo, posiblemente sea un objeto en el que una de sus propiedades es data. Te sugiero que revises lo que devuelve ese método, parece que por ahí está el tema.

Comment: Ya revise y está bien el problema está en el react al colocar la URL del servidor no me funciona y lo tengo así.                         Axios.defaults.baseURL="https://astronomicreact.herokuapp.com/api" esa URL me trae los datos pero en react no.